# Url encoding with French Character

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

i need to pass special characters trough the webservice. i used the code

> HttpUtility.UrlEncode("french character")

but the encoding is not working  correctly if the string contains a double Quots

eg:   `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("é")`

it encodes fine. but not decodes properly

......Thank in advance ......

Comment: Could you provide a little more details? How are you trying to decode? Where, is it in another application? Why is your question tagged `web-services`? If you are trying to call a SOAP web service you should simply generate a client proxy and directly invoke the corresponding method on this proxy. You shouldn't be encoding anything manually. That should be done automatically.

Comment: I got the answer which is mentioned below. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) of the french character  `é` is  `%E9`

when we use

> HttpUtility.UrlEncode("é")

we get the output as   `%c3%a.`

> HttpUtility.UrlEncode("é",
>   System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")

gives the correct encoded output ie `%E9`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what your problem is. This code:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("something enclosed \"in quotes\""));
```

outputs this result:

```
something+enclosed+%22in+quotes%22
```

just as it should, without the `\` character. So what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: but i got some problems in encoding the  French characters like é .It encodes but does not decodes properly..

Comment: sorry for not properly posting the question

Answer (score 0):

```
String output = new String(input.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -2):

It's encoded fine, try:

> HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("somecodes\""))

Comment: What in the world would that accomplish...? That's like saying `x = x + 1 - 1`.

Comment: @SpikeX, it's just so you could see, that when you decode it back, it's decoded properly. It's not an example of how to encode.